# Update scoped variable based on Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-resource, angular-http

I have an Angular app communicating with an external API. I'm able to generate the initial view from an Angular $resource call. My problem is that I have a form that runs a function on ng-click. That function then queries the API again and is supposed to update that same scoped variable but I'm not able to get the results of the second $resource call to update the scoped variable.

In my controller, this is the initial call that gets the data that shows up in the view initially:

`// Initial weather and geolocation data
    var Weather = $resource('http://example.com/:method');
    Weather.get({method: 'current'}).$promise.then(function(weather) {
      // Success
      $scope.weather = weather.weather;
      $scope.geolocation = weather.location;
    }, function(error) {
      // Failure
      $scope.weather = error;
    });`

So far so good, the view updates and I can show the JSON that the API sends back with `{{ weather.currently.temp }}` as well as all the data in the {{ geolocation }} variable.

However, I have a form (it is properly set up to talk to the controller) that upon submission should make another request to the same API and return new data:

`// Search functionality
    $scope.weatherLookup = function(query) {
      $http.get('http://example.com/location/' + query).then(function (value) {
        $scope.weather = value;
      });
    };`

At this point, in the view, the {{ weather }} variable does not update anywhere. At all. If I throw a `console.log` function inside the `weatherLookup` function I get `undefined` when trying to get the value of `$scope.weather` but I do get a valid JSON object when I ask for `value` in that same `console.log()` statement instead.

How can I get that `value` variable assigned to the `$scope.weather` inside `$scope.weatherLookup` so that it can update that value and have it bubble up to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I found - I welcome alternative/better ways to do this.

Apparently `$scope.weather` references multiple values. That is to say, because the $resource and $http methods return promises and the nature of those promises, `$scope.weather` can actually reference two separate objects as far as the view and controller are concerned. The way I solved the problem was by using `$rootScope` to make sure the same `weather` object was always overwritten.

Here's the new code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('WeatherCtrl', function ($scope, Restangular, $rootScope) {

    // Get initial weather data (NOW WITH $rootScope)
    Restangular.one('current').get().then(function(weather) {
      $rootScope.weather = weather.weather;
      $scope.geolocation = weather.location;
    });

    // Search functionality
    $scope.weatherLookup = function(query) {
      Restangular.one('location/' + query).get().then(function(newWeather) {
        $rootScope.weather = newWeather;
        console.log($rootScope.weather);
      });
      console.log($rootScope.weather);
    };

  });
```

I switched from using Angular's own `$resource` and `$http` services to the wonderful [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) library. Despite this change, the original problem persisted until I used `$rootScope`. I tested this theory using `$resource` and `$http` and it still worked so I know that the issue was that `$scope.weather` was somehow splitting off and referencing two separate objects under the hood because of the way `$scope` and promises work in Angular.